# is it possible to build a custom username, password and email authentication code in swift ? (Firebase not included)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, authentication

As part of an app I am building, I want my user to access the app via username, password and email authentication.

I wanted to write my own code to practice rather than rely on Firebase.

PS : I am using Xcode and swift.

To do that, I built a class with username, email and password variables. In the corresponding View controller, I have a button that when pressed, does the following.

- create a new object from the class I mentioned
- provide properties for username, password and email from the textField when the user is creating a new account (i.e : class.username = usernameTextfield.text)
- add this new object to an array that contains only objects from that class
- save the array in user defaults.

here is my code

1. In a separate swift file (Model)

```html
import Foundation
import UIKit
// on cree une classe qui contient les differents elements necessaires pour creer un profil
class SignUpDataModel {
    //user name
    var username: String = ""
    var email: String = ""
    var password: String = ""
    
    //autres details specifiques au profil utilisateur
    var nationality: String = ""
}
```

2. In the view controller file

```html
 
    @IBOutlet weak var userNameTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var emailTextField: UITextField!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    
    // on cree un tableau qui va contenir nos donnees sauvegardees de type SignUpDataModel
    var savedNewUserData = [SignUpDataModel]()
    
    // on cree une variable user defaults
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    
    // on cree une variable qui va contenir la clé qu'on va utiliser en sauvegardant les donnees dans user defaults
    var userDefaultsKey: String = "NewUserData"
    
    
    

    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

    @IBAction func NewProfileButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        //chaque fois qu'on clique sur ce bouton
        // on appelle la fonction qui gere un nouvel utilisateur créé
        newUserCreation()
        // ensuite on fait le segue vers le user profile VC
        
    }
    
    //MARK: - Function that handles signing Up whenever you tap on the sign un button
    func newUserCreation() {
        // on cree un nouvel objet de type signUpDataModel
        let newProfile = SignUpDataModel()
        // on lui donne des valeurs pour username, email et password
        newProfile.username = userNameTextField.text!
        newProfile.email = emailTextField.text!
        newProfile.password = passwordTextField.text!
        // on l'ajoute au tableau savedNewUserData
        savedNewUserData.append(newProfile)
        // et on sauvegarde le tout dans user defaults
        defaults.set(savedNewUserData, forKey: userDefaultsKey)
        
        // on a une alerte :
        print("success: username:\(newProfile.username), password:\(newProfile.password), email:\(newProfile.email) have beed successfully added to user defaults")
        
    }
```

Comment: You cannot save an array of custom objects directly to `UserDefaults`, you have to serialize it as JSON or Property List. And you don't need a class, a struct is sufficient. And to ***append*** the  new data you have to load the array first from `UserDefaults`, append the new item and save it back.

Comment: You shouldn't be storing sensitive info in userDefaults. Are you saving the array both in Firebase and in user defaults? I'm a bit unclear on what you are trying to do.

Comment: @rs7 I did not wish to use firebase this time around to configure authentication. Since I am a beginner in programming I wanted to practice my fundamentals (and authentication via Firebase I already know how to do). Rather I wanted to create an object for each new user with username, email and password. Those properties would be used for authentication, and I wanted to store those credentials in user defaults. Hence my code

Comment: What if someone deletes  your app and reinstalls it? All that userdefault data is gone. If the user tries to sign in or won’t let him. You could store the credentials in Keychain.. and later if you decide to use a cloud solution to make your app available on multiple platforms you could find a way to import that data.

Comment: @rs7 that will teach me to  get fancy. I so wanted to see if I could build my own custom code lol. I gens I shall use firebase after all. Thank you for your answers and counsel.